# Gridview 100% inside a div

Tags: html, css, asp.net, gridview

so on my webpage i have 3 divs that are floated and flex (and inside another div)and the middle div currently has a gridview here is a simplified version of the code

```
<div style=" width:100%; display:flex; height:inherit" >
            <div style=" flex: 1; float:left; padding: 1em; padding-bottom: 15em; margin-bottom: -15em; ">
            (code...)
            </div>
            <div style="flex: 1; float:left; padding: 1em; border-right:1px solid gray; border-left:1px solid gray; ">    
            <asp:GridView ID="dgvMarcacoes" runat="server" OnRowDataBound = "OnRowDataBound" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" >
                    <Columns>

                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Data" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Utente" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Nome" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Série" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Tipo" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Estado" />

                    </Columns>    
                    <SelectedRowStyle BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" />
            </asp:GridView>    
            </div> 

            <div style=" flex: 1; float:left; padding: 1em; padding-bottom: 15em; margin-bottom: -15em;">
            (code...)
            </div> 
    </div>
```

and im trying do make the grid 100% width but unsuccessfully, i have tried adding `width=100%` on the grid code like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvMarcacoes" runat="server" OnRowDataBound = "OnRowDataBound" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" width=100%>
```

and also adding a style like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvMarcacoes" runat="server" OnRowDataBound = "OnRowDataBound" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" style="width:100%" >
```

but it stays the same ... here is a pic of how it is atm : [image: pic] any help here? (btw the grid im trying to stretch is the one in de middle div (div2)) thanks,

EDIT:So i tried removing one of the columns to see if the problem was the grid being too big but its the same here is a pic [image: pic]

Comment: Your GridView is too wide, it just doesn't fit. Remove a column or use CSS `word-break: break-all`

Comment: i removed a column to see if it was the problem but no, it stays the same il edit my question with a print of how it stays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i solved it by removing `padding: 1em;` from the middle div